# Python Pandas - How to convert datetime64[ns] and get hours and minutes only from it?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a pandas dateframe that contains a datetime64[ns] column named, 'Submit Date.' From this row of syntax, it will output a row value as:

Code:

`TicketsDF[['submitDate']] = (TicketsDF[['submitDate']].apply(pd.to_datetime, unit="s")) - timedelta(hours= +5)`

Output is:

2022-04-15 15:52.37

How do I just grab the hours and minutes from this value? I'm needing to grab it because later on, I need to check to see if that time is between a start and end time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dt.time for hours and minutes.

```
out = TicketsDF[['submitDate']].dt.time
```

Here is more information:

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.time.html

Comment: I tried that but for some reason I get the following error when I tried this syntax ( I wanted a new column named, 'SubmitTime'):

`TicketsDF['submitTime'] = TicketsDF[['submitDate']].dt.time`


AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dt'

Comment: Could you show the column in your question (an screen shot or a sample) which you want to change the time?

Comment: Here is screenshot of date and time:

https://ibb.co/VS3DCGb

Ultimately what I need to do is take the time only and check if it's between 9:00AM and 6PM. If it is, true, if not, false.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pandas.Series.dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) which returns string type

```py
TicketsDF['submitDate'].dt.strftime('%H:%M')
```

If you care about the type, you can try remove seconds and use `dt.time` accessor.

```py
TicketsDF['submitDate'].dt.floor('min').dt.time
```